# Try set initial pool size of database connections (spring-boot)

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, connection-pooling

So, i have a application that uses spring-boot 1.4.0 and a Oracle database. I'm trying to define the number of connections of the pool in the application.properties, using these configs:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url = url
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.maxActive= x
spring.datasource.initialSize= y
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1 from dual
```

And i'm using the query

```
select *from V$SESSION where username= 'username';
```

to check the database connections, but when i run the application it's always using 10 connections, despite what i define as the initialSize. I tried to check other stackoverflow answers and examples on GitHub and i don't know why it's not working, so i would appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Spring Boot 1.4 [does not bind the `DataSource` in the `spring.datasource` namespace anymore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#datasource-binding). Each supported connection pool implementations have a dedicated namespace for their respective keys. You are probably looking at older samples.

You first need to identify which connection pool you are using (if you're relying on the starter you should probably get the Tomcat JDBC pool, see `spring.datasource.tomcat`). Use your IDE to get the list of keys you can use.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. By default spring-boot uses Tomcat and adding "spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=x" solved the problem.

Comment: The default is 10, this looks fairly random to me, it could have been 7 or 12 instead, has anyone tried using 5 ? I suppose if the database is not used intensively this will have little impact.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy : Sizing the connection pool is apparently quite a science. There is an interesting article on the subject here : https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Comment: Just in case the link goes down: `(core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count`